# The right test for word usage in corpus linguistics

Tags: corpus-linguistics

I need to find the right statistical test to use here:

[image: data]

the words on the left are prepositions.
the groups are beginner, Intermediate, and advanced level speakers of Swedish
My hypothesis is that there is no significant difference between any of the groups in terms of the frequency of usage of the prepositions
However, there may be a significant difference in individual items in the list.
I'm trying to wrap my head around which statistical test to use.

Comment: Welcome Aaron :-) I interpreted the numbers in your list as percentages on first sight, but that does obviously not make sense - what are they actually, frequency per 1000 prepositions? And how big are your groups (beginner, intermediate, advanced)? If it is frequency per 1000 prepositions, do you then still have the original data (number of prepositions in all per participant)? And if yes to the last question - was text length roughly the same for all participants?

Comment: You should give the data as counts, then what you have is a contingency table. Present that table as raw counts (which you then can use for chi-square test), but also as row-wise percents (for interpretation).  For helping interpretation, you could also order the rows after percentage of first column, maybe. After doing this, and presenting the results as an edit to the post, maybe other ideas could be presented!